# How can I make this image grid responsive in html/css?

Tags: html, css, image, styles

You can view the site at http://acute.design.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
Basically I'm trying to make an image grid for a portfolio. It looks great at 1080p but below that it's a jumble of trash.
Any help with this would be awesome :)

Comment: Please post your code as a verifiable example. I doubt anyone would download anything without knowing what it is. Furthermore, if this Download Resource is not available anymore in the future, this question becomes unsolvable

Comment: Thanks. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if the truth is you're looking for this because the question is not entirely clear. but this is what I did I hope I help you.

Change the margin:

```
img {
    transition: all 300ms;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0.3%;
}
```